# Trying to host ASP.NET MVC website on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have server, with static IP. All I want is to make my ASP.NET MVC 5 webstite work on this server. I have follow many tutorials. But none of them does not give me expected result. I was facing many troubles, IIS could not read config file, file browsering disable etc, etc. I was fixing all of them. In one moment I have got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIuKH.png) instead of Login page which should be default(I changed it in config and IIS default files). When I try to open my Views I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qau0.png).
I was googling this problem. But none of solutions from internet does not help. Pls let me know if you need more information. Im stacked, pls help.

Comment: It looks like you just copied files. you need to publish the site which you can do to a folder, then copy those files to where you want them for IIS.

Comment: @Crowcoder I published my site

Answer (score 0):

[image]

problem 1: Directory browsing: needs to be turned off.

problem 2: Default document: specify the actual filename. Doublecheck that it's in there and marked at top. I for example have a website which has a different named file, which is not in the default IIS settings, and I have to re-add it every time I publish.